# Using the ToggleButton to send data to another activity on Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on a project where I want a group of togglebuttons to send data to another activity in android.

I want the togglebuttons to send data to another activity based on the ones that are clicked. Here's the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_start2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.brillica.vapid.Start2">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/question" />

<ToggleButton
    android:textOff="Sports"
    android:textOn="Sports"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:id="@+id/sports"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#DDA388"/>

<ToggleButton
    android:textOff="Science"
    android:textOn="Science"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/science"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#DDA388"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sports"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sports"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:textOff="Art"
    android:textOn="Art"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/art"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#DDA388"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/science"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/science"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:textOff="Entertainment"
    android:textOn="Entertainment"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/entertainment"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#DDA388"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:textOff="Crafting"
    android:textOn="Crafting"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/reading"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#DDA388"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/entertainment"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/entertainment"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:textOff="Farming"
    android:textOn="Farming"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/farming"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#DDA388"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/reading"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reading"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/art"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/art" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:background="#DDA388"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:layout_below="@+id/entertainment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

If for example togglebutton science and togglebutton art are clicked, I want text in another activity to change to "Art and Science" once button next is clicked, and if art is clicked alone, I want the TextView to display Art once button next is clicked.

I am new to programming so I am not that experienced with code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should be calling the new activity with an Intent.

You can add extras to your intent to pass data between activites.

```
mIntent.putExtra("sciencebutton", scbutton.isChecked());
```

You can get the buttons programatically by doing:

```
ToggleButton scbutton = findViewById(R.id.science);
```

In the second activity:

```
boolean isScienceButtonChecked = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("sciencebutton");
```

will return the value you passed in the first activity (in this case whether or not the science button was checked)

Comment: That makes sense, but can you give an instance where you access it in the textView?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "access it in the textView". Do you mean send what is inside of a textView between activities? Or do you mean populate a textView in the second activity based on which buttons are checked in the first?

Comment: I want the textView to indicate that the toggleButton was checked for example if scbtn.isChecked{tv.setText("Hello")} that is in the second activity

Comment: You've got the right idea already. Just use the boolean returned from the getIntent(). `if (isScienceButtonChecked) { tv.setText("Hello") }`

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense but I don't know how to set the TextView to science once the Intent is passed.